# Eclipse Auto-Correct?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there a way to have Eclipse auto-correct certain misspellings? For example, I tend to type "System" as "Sysetm", and Eclipse catches it. However, it only tells me it's an invalid package, and I have to manually correct it. I'm hoping there's a way like in Microsoft Word, where you can add words to be auto-corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Trust me you don't want something like that. It would make it almost impossible to write code with it changing what it thinks you want a variable called. Also its use would be very limited.

I have a hard enough time trying to convince word I mean colour and not color.

Comment: I honestly don't have many mistakes, but the ones I do, I make quite often, so it would be quite useful. I wouldn't name a variable "Sysetm" anyways...

Comment: I'm with James on this one.  There isn't a piece of software in existence where I haven't turned off autocorrect.  I always try it, always get burned.  Like right now, eclipse keeps auto-changing my call `validator.getValidInput()` to `Validator.getValidInput()`  Two entirely different calls.

Comment: Trust me you don't get to tell people what they do or don't want.

Comment: switching from delphi to java 29 times a day, I'd really like := to turn into = and then to turn into {

Answer (score 1):

try to use "alt+/" after input 'sys'

Comment: Just gives me: sys÷  (Using Mac)